# Timer para esperar respuesta de servidor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api

Tengo un bucle el cual hace un método post a una API.

Quiero tener un timer para limitar la respuesta del servidor. Cuando lance la consulta a la API que espere durante 30 o 40 segundos la respuesta del servidor. Si la recibe en ese tiempo que continue con el código que hay después, sino la recibe en ese tiempo, lanzar un error de timeout.

Mientras esta esperando la respuesta, no quiero que avance con el resto del codigo. He probado con setTimeout, pero no lo veo estable a largo plazo(al menos de la forma que lo he usado),y con setinterval no consigo hacerlo. Que forma podría hacerlo?

```
async req(){
  for (let index = 1; index <= this.numerototal; index++) {
    this.pservice.Irequest(this.crequest).subscribe(data => {
      await this.timeout(30000);
      if (data.type === 'success') {
        //código....

      } else {
        //código...
      }
    });
  }
  timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }
```

Gracias.

Comment: Proporciona tu código por favor!

Comment: Añadido! De todas formas, no creo que sea de mucha ayuda. Como digo, no acaba de hacer lo que realmente necesitaría...

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el operador `timeout` y `catchError` de rxjs

```
async req(){
    for (let index = 1; index <= this.numerototal; index++) { 
      
     this.pservice.Irequest(this.crequest)
         .pipe(
           timeout(30000),
           catchError((error) => of({type: 'error'}))
         ) 
         .subscribe(data => {

          if (data.type === 'success') {
           //código....  
           
          } else {
             //código...
          }
  
        });
     }
```

Con `timeout` establecemos el tiempo máximo a esperar y con `catchError` devolvemos un observable con el valor del error para ser manejado en el subscribe